# regex by ip file contains subnet lines

Tags: regex, bash, unix, ip, cidr

I need to regexp by IP addresses file, which contain subnet addresses in this format:

*some_grep_command -c 192.168.1.11 white_list_file*
1

цhite_list_file contain line 192.168.1. All subnet in file with /24 cidr mask. Therefore, this record is not used therein.

Something like inverted grepcidr. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Please, show minimal sample of all input files and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends on whether the subnet mask is always going to be 24 bits, if that's the case just regex the first 3 octets.

If the subnet mask is going to change then you'll probably want to capture each octet separately.  Convert the subnet mask to it's 4 octet equivalent, then bitwise AND each octet and reassemble.